# The inversions of an array and the number of it

Tags: analysis, proof-verification, algorithms

Let $A=[A[1],\dots, A[n]]$ be an array for $n\in \mathbb{N}$.

An inversion is a pair $(i,j)$ such that $A[i]>A[j]$ and $i<j$.

**Example**: Let $B=[4,1,6,2,3,8]$ be an array. Since $(1,v)$ for $v\in \{2,3,5\}$ and $(3,w)$ for $w\in \{4,5\}$, there are $5$ inversions in $B$.

> 1) For every $n$, how many inversions can $A$ maximum have?

**My answer**: Assume that $A[1]>A[2]>\dots >A[n]$. Note that
\begin{align*}A[1]>A[k_{1}] &\textrm{ and } 1<k_{1} \textrm{ for } k_{2}\in \{2,3,\dots, n\}\\
A[2]>A[k_{2}] &\textrm{ and } 2<k_{2} \textrm{ for } k_{2}\in \{3,4,\dots, n\}\\
&\quad \vdots\\
A[n-1]>A[n] &\textrm{ and } n-1<n,
\end{align*}
so we totally have 
$$
\begin{align*} &\qquad \left | \{2,3,\dots, n\} \right |+\left | \{3,4,\dots, n\} \right |+\dots +\left | \{n\} \right |\\
& =(n-1)+(n-2)+\dots+1=\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}i=\frac{n(n+1)}{2}-n
\end{align*}
$$
inversions in $A$.

> 2) Write a pseudocode, that counts the number of inversions in $A$.

**My answer**: I am not good at writing it. I think it would be like this

```
inv(A,i,j)
   if i < j: Return True
   if A[i] > A[j]: Return True
   Elseif A[i] <= A[j]: Return inv(A,i+1,j)
print len(inv(A,i,j))       // Number of the inversions in A.
```

Does this code make sense? I have looked at some places, like [this](http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/counting-inversions/). In this case, I just want to make a short code. Thanks for your time!

Comment: You could write your answer to (1) as $\dfrac{n(n-1)}{2}$.  It is correct

Comment: It is difficult for me to anticipate what counting of inversions might be implemented by such pseudo-code.  It seems as you are defining a recursive procedure `inv(A,i,j)` but only a return value `True` is possible.  I'm not sure what to make of the line  that prints `len(inv(A,i,j))` especially since arguments `i,j` appear never to be instantiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is in pseudocode a routine that counts the number of inversions.

```
1. inversionsOf(array)
2.    n := length(array).
3.    count := 0.
4.    for i = 1 to n do: 
5.      {ai := array[i].
6.      for j = i + 1 to n do: 
7.          {aj := array[j].
8.          if (ai > aj) do: {count := count + 1}}}.
9.    return count
```

I've numbered the lines for reference in the comments that follow:

1. The name of the routine (or function) is `inversionsOf`, the input parameter `array` designs an hypothetical array of numbers whose inversions we are about to count. The pseudo-code that evaluates this function at your example array is `inversionsOf([4,1,6,2,3,8])`.
2. Variable `n` stands for the number of elements in `array`. We assume that such a number can be deduced from the array by a certain function `length()`. The actual way to get the array length depends on the concrete programming language.
3. Variable `count` stands for the counter. We initialize it to `0` and will increment it by `1` every time we detect an inversion. At the end `count` will hold the number of inversions in `array`.
4. The `for ... = ... to ... do: {...}` pseudo code will evaluate the expression between curly brackets in sequence, once for every value of the iteration variable (the one just before the equal sign). In this case the `{expression(i)}` will be evaluated for `i` in the integer interval $[1, n]$. In this case the expression is the one that spans between lines 5 and 8.
5. At every value of `i` we define `ai` as the `i`th element of `array`. The pseudo code for reading this element is `array[i]`. When `i=1` the value of `ai` will be `array[1]`, meaning the first element of the array. When `i=2` `ai` will be the second element, etc. Note that the `i` in `ai` is a fixed letter, do not interprete it as the variable `i`. The iteration from `i=1` to `n` will scan the entire array.
6. For every position `i` inside the array, we visit all the entries of the array with positions above the current value of `i`. This is achieved with another `for` enumeration, this time from `i+1` (rather than `1`) to `n`. Note that the iteration variable is named `j` to avoid confusion with `i`. In this case the `{expression(j)}` evaluated for every value of `j` is the one that goes from line 7 to line 8.
7. Here we read the `j`th entry of the array and name it `aj` (once again the `j` in `aj` is just a letter.)
8. Here is where the actual counting happens. If `ai > aj` then we are in presence of an inversion. Therefore, in such a case we increment the counter. If there is no inversion between `i` and `j` we do nothing. In either case we are at the end of `{expression(j)}` and so we increment `j` by `1` and start over in line 7. Once `j` reaches `n+1`, we increment `i` and go back to line 5. When `i` reaches `n+1` we exit the `for` enumeration at 6 and go to 9.
9. At this point `count` contains the number of inversions in `array`, so we exit the function returning its value as the result.

Comment: It might be more helpful to the OP if you were to review the pseudo-code that was posted in the Question (for the second part).  In any case you will surely be more helpful to your Readers if you address the first part of the Question and give some explanation of your pseudo-code (perhaps in the form of "code commenting"?)

Comment: @hardmath many thanks for encouraging me so kindly.

Comment: I left a comment for the OP about their pseudo-code, and I hope they will benefit from your detailed explanation.